# Integrate multiple Android apps

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a few `com.android.application` modules (that imports their own libraries, etc), but instead of dumping all the sources into one module, I want to have a module that calls them.

However, when I want to call an `Activity` from the new integrated module, Android Studio is unable to find the Activity class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selector_activity);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    Button button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.selector_Button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.myCompany.referenceApp.activity.SplashActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the build.gradle of the integrated module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.integratedgui"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':referenceapp')
}
```

Android Studio will always fail the compilation and prompt "Alt Enter" to include the dependency on module "referenceapp", and keep adding the statement `compile project(path: ':referenceapp')` which is already in the build file.

What must I do to be able to include many different applications into this integrated app, which will call them individually?

Answer (score 0):

To import multiple projects in Android Studio.
In settings.gradle file ,Add all modules like this for example:

```
include ':nxpnfcandroidlib'
include ':sampleNxpNfcLib'
include ':AndrSdkTestBench'
project(":sampleNxpNfcLib").projectDir = file("../../02_Samples/sampleNxpNfcLib")
project(":AndrSdkTestBench").projectDir = file("../../04_Test/AndrSdkTestBench/app")
```

If Any of these modules need to be added as dependency then you can add below code for example:

`compile project(':nxpnfcandroidlib')` in Build.gradle file